# AWS Sagemaker Multiple Training Jobs

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, scikit-learn, amazon-sagemaker

We currently have a system running on AWS Sagemaker whereby several units have their own trained machine learning model artifact (using an SKLearn training script with the Sagemaker SKLearn estimator).

Through the use of Sagemaker's multi-model endpoints, we are able to host all of these units on a single instance.

The problem we have is that we need to scale this system up such that we can train individual models for hundreds of thousand of units and then host the resulting model artifacts on a multi-model endpoint. But, Sagemaker has a limit to the number of models you can train in parallel (our limit is 30).

Aside from training our models in batches, does anyone have any ideas how to go about implementing a system in AWS Sagemaker whereby for hundreds of thousands of units, we can have a separate trained model artifact for each unit?

Is there a way to output multiple model artifacts for 1 sagemaker training job with the use of an SKLearn estimator?

Furthermore, how does Sagemaker make use of multiple CPUs when a training script is submitted? Does this have to be specified in the training script/estimator object or is this handled automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some ideas:

***1. does anyone have any ideas how to go about implementing a system in AWS Sagemaker whereby for hundreds of thousands of units, we can have a separate trained model artifact for each unit? Is there a way to output multiple model artifacts for 1 sagemaker training job with the use of an SKLearn estimator?***

I don't know if the 30-training job concurrency is a hard limit, if it is a blocker you should try and open a support ticket to ask if it is and try and get it raised. Otherwise as you can point out, you can try and train multiple models in one job, and produce multiple artifacts that you can either (a) send to S3 manually, or (b) save to `opt/ml/model` so that they all get sent to the model.tar.gz artifact in S3. Note that if this artifact gets too big this could get impractical though

***2. how does Sagemaker make use of multiple CPUs when a training script is submitted? Does this have to be specified in the training script/estimator object or is this handled automatically?***

This depends on the type of training container you are using. SageMaker built-in containers are developed by Amazon teams and designed to efficiently use available resources. If you use your own code such as custom python in the Sklearn container, you are responsible for making sure that your code is efficiently written and uses available hardware. Hence framework choice is quite important :) for example, some sklearn models support explicitly using multiple CPUs (eg the `n_jobs` parameter in the [random forest](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html)), but I don't think that Sklearn natively supports GPU, multi-GPU or multi-node training.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you've pretty much confirmed what we thought

Comment: Thank you Olivier. That was what we were thinking as well:)

Comment: RAPIDS cuML is a GPU machine learning library with a scikit-learn-like API that can be used with SageMaker. GPU-accelerated estimators are generally significantly faster on large datasets. This page may have some links that are worth exploring: https://rapids.ai/cloud.html#AWS-Sagemaker